# merge 2 xml file with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files persons1 and persons2 and I want to merge them in one xml file using xslt , I m new in xslt so any help will be appreciated :
first file persons1:

```
<personnes>
  <personne>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>bbb</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>ccc</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <name>ddd</name>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>


</personnes>
```

second file persons2:

```
<personnes>
  <personne>

    <id>1111</id>
    <quantity>1100</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

     <id>2222</id>
     <quantity>2200</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>3333</id>
    <quantity>3300</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>4444</id>
    <quantity>4400</quantity>
  </personne>

  <personne>

    <id>5555</id>
    <quantity>5500</quantity>
  </personne>
</personnes>
```

and I want the result in a new xml file like bellow :

```
<personnes>
  <personne>
    <id>1111</id>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <quantity>1100</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>2222</id>
    <name>bbb</name>
    <quantity>2200</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>aaaaaa</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>3333</id>
    <name>ccc</name>
    <quantity>3300</quantity>
    <age>20</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>

  <personne>
    <id>4444</id>
    <name>ddd</name>
    <quantity>4400</quantity>
    <age>10</age>
    <adress>cccccc</adress>
  </personne>


</personnes>
```

I want to  take id and quantity from the file: persons2  and put them  in the xml file:persons1 so one by one that mean fisrt with the first , second with second etc...

Comment: Please post your attempted XSLT script and errors or undesired results that occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSL file that should accomplish what you are looking for out of the merge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- load the merge file -->
<xsl:variable name="personne2"
  select="document('file2.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<personnes>
<xsl:for-each select="personnes/personne">


<xsl:variable name="elementposition" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>

   <!-- copy the child nodes -->
   <personne>

   <xsl:copy-of select="$personne2/personnes//personne[position() = $elementposition]/id"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::name"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$personne2/personnes//personne[position() = $elementposition]/quantity"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::age"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="child::address"/>

   </personne>
</xsl:for-each>
</personnes>
```

Comment: thank you for the response: I got the result but just in different order like this :  in personne node: id,quantity,name,age,address but I want : id, name , quantity,age,address.

Comment: @OmarB. I have modified the code snippet in my original answer to match your desired output order.  Note: it's hopefully clear how you could now easily move around the order of the output by specifying the child elements.  Good Luck.

Comment: can you please explain to me what that line do : <xsl:variable name="elementposition" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/> . I m learning xslt or if you have any tutorial, I will appreciate.

Comment: Sure it is pretty simple.  It saying create a variable to track the element position.  We are currently in a loop of the personne elements, so it says get all of the preceeding-sibling elements (all the <personne> elements before the current) and take a count of them. Then add 1 to give an accurate number for the current position.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:variable name="doc" select="document('person2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="personnes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="personne">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:if test=".[$pos=$doc/personnes/personne/position()]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$doc/personnes/personne[position() =$pos]/id"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="child::name">
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test=".[$pos=$doc/personnes/personne/position()]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$doc/personnes/personne[position() =$pos]/quantity"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="child::age">
                    <age>
                        <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
                    </age>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="child::adress">
                    <adress>
                        <xsl:value-of select="adress"/>
                    </adress>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:copy>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
You may also try this
```

Comment: thank you , I got an Xpath error is invalid at this line  : <xsl:if test=".[$pos=$doc/personnes/personne/position()]"> . do you know why please.